# For-statement to iterate through items in a list for an if-statement

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement

Apologies for the basic question, I'm new to Python & struggling to find an answer.

How do I execute the below *if-statement* for each item in the list *loaded_route*?

i.e. check the first *loaded_route* value, update *location*, then check the next value, update *location* etc.

My current *for-loop* compares the entire list, not individual values. Thanks!

```
location = [1,1]
loaded_route = ['right', 'left']
route_coords = []

for route in loaded_route:
    if route == 'right':
        location[0] = (location[0] + 1)
        route_coords.append(location)
    elif route == 'left':
        location[0] = (location[0] - 1)
        route_coords.append(location)
    elif route == 'up':
        location[1] = (location[1] - 1)
        route_coords.append(location)
    elif route == 'down':
        location[1] = (location[1] + 1)
    else:
        print('failed to read loaded_route')
```

Comment: Are you sure it's _comparing_ the entire list? Have another look at what your `append`ing to your `route_coords` ;)

Comment: I'm confused. That loop does what you're describing, unless you're describing it wrong (no offense, we all start somewhere). Please show us your desired output and actual output. Like, maybe you want to `print(location)` each loop? It's not clear. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: Oh, are you looking at `route_coords` at the end and seeing all the values are the same? That's working as expected since they're all the same object. If you want to copy `location` each time you append it, there's an existing question: [How do I clone a list so that it doesn't change unexpectedly after assignment?](/q/2612802/4518341)

Comment: Well don't I feel silly... Thanks Zoltán & wjandrea for helping me out so fast - not a mistake I'll make again in a hurry!

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why does foo.append(bar) affect all elements in a list of lists?](/q/6360286/4518341)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`location` is type list, and lists are "mutable" in Python. That means that every time you add `location` to `route_coords`, you are merely inserting a reference to `location`, which is allowed to keep changing.

Instead, you want to make a copy of the current location value to `route_coords`.

```
location = [1,1]
loaded_route = ['right', 'left']
route_coords = []

for route in loaded_route:
    if route == 'right':
        location[0] = (location[0] + 1)
        route_coords.append(location[:])
    elif route == 'left':
        location[0] = (location[0] - 1)
        route_coords.append(location[:])
    elif route == 'up':
        location[1] = (location[1] - 1)
        route_coords.append(location[:])
    elif route == 'down':
        location[1] = (location[1] + 1)
        route_coords.append(location[:])
    else:
        print('failed to read loaded_route')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping so quickly, that's exactly what I was looking for but didn't know how to word my search for [:].